# Information theory: typical set proof

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy

I'm trying to understand this proof from my information theory class. It's a proof of the property of the typical set.

Prove the following:

$$ 2^{-n(1+\epsilon)H(X)}\leq p(x^n) \leq 2^{-n(1-\epsilon)H(X)}\quad \text{and} \quad \displaystyle 2^{-n(1+\epsilon)H(Y)}\leq p(y^n) \leq 2^{-n(1-\epsilon)H(Y)}$$

> *Proof:* Note that
>   $$\begin{align}
> \frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{1}{p(x^n)}\right) &=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{1}{p_X(x_i)}\right) \\
> &= \sum_{x\in \chi} \frac{1}{n}N(x\vert x^n)\log\left(\frac{1}{p_X(x_i)}\right) \tag{1}
> \end{align}$$
>   For $x^n \in \mathcal{T}_\epsilon^{(n)}(X)$, we have $$
> (1-\epsilon)P_X(x)\leq \frac{1}{n}N(x\vert x^n)\leq(1+\epsilon)P_X(x),\quad x\in\chi \tag{2}
> $$
>   Combining (1) and (2) shows that $2^{-n(1+\epsilon)H(X)}\leq p(x^n) \leq 2^{-n(1-\epsilon)H(X)}$ By symmetry, we have $\displaystyle 2^{-n(1+\epsilon)H(Y)}\leq p(y^n) \leq 2^{-n(1-\epsilon)H(Y)}$

I understand how they reach eq 1  and 2 but I don't really understand how eq 1 and 2 completes the proof as the last line says.Can anyone give me a pointer on where to start?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: The second line of (1) is wrong, it should have $1/p_X(x)$, not $1/p_X(x_i)$. This step is collating all the $x_i$ which take the value $x$ together - this is where the $N$ comes from. Also the $P$s in (2) should be $p$, for consistency. With these corrections, its only a matter of substituting the pointwise bounds of (2) into (1). For instance, plugging in the upper bounds, gives you $1/n \log(1/p(x^n)) \le \sum_{ x \in \mathcal{X}} (1+\epsilon) p_X(x) \log(1/p_X(x)) = (1+\epsilon) H(X)$ which can be rearranged to  $p(x^n) \ge 2^{-n(1+\epsilon)H(X)}$